# Struts 2 textfield label doesn't show in table

Tags: struts2, tags, textfield

The following jsp file fragment using struts2 tags doesn't show the textfield label. How can I fix this? Is it possible to have the label displayed by using only struts2 tags?

```
<s:form action="voucher" theme="simple">
    <table  width=50% border="5"> 
      <tr>
          <td>
         <s:textfield label="Enter the voucher hrn"  name="voucher.SN" />
          </td>
          <td>
         <s:submit value="Check state" />
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
         <s:radio  list="#{'used': 'Mark as used', 'available': 'Mark as available'}" name="selections" value="%{'used'}"></s:radio>
          </td>
          <td>
         <s:submit value="Update state" />
          </td>
      </tr>
        </table>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are using `simple` theme in your form. Remove `theme="simple"` from `<s:form>` tag then Struts2 will do table layout as well field errors and labels for you.
BTW if you really need to use your custom layout then use `<s:label>` tags for labels.

Comment: Removing the theme gives a weird layout. Adding a label tag gives the wanted page display. Thanks!